Pyth V2 migration for projects with older dependencies (pull oracles)
At the end of June 2024, Pyth push oracles will be discontinued, so all programs that currently use them must migrate to pull oracles.
The drop-in replacement is to consume Price Feed Accounts. To use these on-chain, Pyth provides an sdk: https://crates.io/crates/pyth-solana-receiver-sdk
However, the SDK uses a relatively new version of many dependencies (for example Anchor >=28), while many projects that have been consuming Pyth oracles for some time are locked to older dependencies. For example, we have a project on:
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.24.2"
anchor-spl = { version = "0.24.2", features = ["dex"] }
solana-program = "1.7"
pyth-sdk-solana = "0.7.0"

In many cases, the project has nested dependencies outside of our control.
How can we update to the new pyth oracle without updating dependencies?

Use the pyth-min crate instead: https://crates.io/crates/pyth-min/0.1.1
This crate uses zero dependencies, and relies on reading the Pyth account from raw bytes as an UncheckedAccount:
let data = &ctx.accounts.price_acc.try_borrow_data()?[..][8..];
let price_v2 = PriceUpdateV2::get_price_update_v2_from_bytes(data);

let price = price_v2.get_price_no_older_than(
    &Clock::get()?.unix_timestamp,
    MAXIMUM_AGE, // in seconds
    None, // Pass the feed ID in bytes if you want to validate it
)?;

Fork, view source, or contribute at: https://github.com/mithraiclabs/pyth-min
See reference implementation of usage at: https://github.com/mithraiclabs/pyth-min-ref
